# Kendo UI Mobile FORM POST not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, mobile, kendo-ui

I hope that someone can help me.

Actually, I have a **MVC app with Kendo UI for Mobile Views**. I have a **problem with a Form with Post methot that not launch this and It does nothing**.

I mean that, a MobileView, has a Form with a Buttom. When I do click on this button, nothing happen, the page not launch the POST and I've to do all via ajax call, but in some case not is the best way to do in the app.

The code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MobileView()
.Name("tabstrip-profile")  
.Layout("mobile-tabstrip")
.Content(obj =>
  Html.Kendo().MobileListView().Style("inset").Type("group")
      .Items(root =>
      {
          root.Add().Text("Update Details").Items(items =>
          {
              items.Add().Content(
                  @<text>
                        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateDetails", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post" }))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                            <fieldset>
                                    <legend></legend>
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobId)
                                    <div class="hContent">
                                        <div>
                                            <h1>Hello, click on the buttom</h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                        }
                  </text>
                );

              items.Add().Content(
              @<text>
                <div style="text-align: right; margin-top: 20px;">
                    <input class="km-button" type="submit" id="btnUdpJob" value="Update Details" />
                </div>
              </text>);
          });
      })
      ))
```

**What is the problem of this? For Why the method is not executed?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without seeing the rendered HTML, but it looks like your `submit` button is outside your `<form>`.